# Image grid on website, can I scale images down with CSS?

Tags: css, image, scaling

I have a lot of images with a resolution around 500x1500 and I want to show all those images in a grid on my website. Each picture in the grid should be 200x200px.

If I scale down the images with CSS from 500x1500px to 200x200px and I show 10 200x200px images on my website, does this mean that the visitor first have to download the 500x1500px images and then their browser scales the pictures down?

If that is the case, then it's a bad solution to do it like this, right? Instead I should have two versions of each picture, one 500x1500px version and one 200x200px version. Am I right?

The question then is what's the easiest way to scale down hundreds of images?

Comment: Or you could use a particular client side library too , or a server side , that would allow only a particular size of image to be sent to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it is the case that the browser will download the larger image and then scale it. You can check for yourself by opening the dev tools on the browser (press F12 if you're using Chrome) and monitoring the network traffic when you reload your site.

The easiest way to scale down hundreds of images is find or write a program to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You can set height and width of the images but 1) the user will have to download a bigger image than necessary and 2) the height x width ratio will be trouble (the big one is 1x3 and the small one is 1x1). I would either use http://www.imagemagick.org/ , gimp or a similar tool to crop the images, but the problem is that the cropped area might not be very good. Only a human can select a good fit for the cropped area :-(

Edit1: Perhaps a well-trained neural network could select the most "interesting" part of every image programatically but that's kind of a lot of trouble to do that. Still it could be pretty interesting :-)